# Uneven tabular vertical padding when using \arraystretch and m-columns

Tags: tables

When I use \arraystretch to add padding around my cells, the padding above each cell is larger than the padding below, causing my text to be off-center. I read about using \\ as a substitute, but this breaks the cell borders. Does anyone have an alternate workaround to this problem? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.8}
\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}|M{0.3in}|M{3in}|M{0.3in}|M{3in}|@{}}
    \hline
    1 & & 11 & \\ \hline
    2 & & 12 & \\ \hline
    3 & & 13 & \\ \hline
    4 & & 14 & \\ \hline
    5 & & 15 & \\ \hline
    6 & & 16 & \\ \hline
    7 & & 17 & \\ \hline
    8 & & 18 & \\ \hline
    9 & & 19 & \\ \hline
    10 & & 20 & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just automatically add an invisible rule at the beginning of  one of the columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}| >{\rule[-0.3in]{0pt}{0.6in}}M{0.3in}|M{3in}|M{0.3in}|M{3in}|@{}}
\hline
1 & & 11 & \\ \hline
2 & & 12 & \\ \hline
3 & & 13 & \\ \hline
4 & & 14 & \\ \hline
5 & & 15 & \\ \hline
6 & & 16 & \\ \hline
7 & & 17 & \\ \hline
8 & & 18 & \\ \hline
9 & & 19 & \\ \hline
10 & & 20 & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]